# Why have we not yet mastered our understanding of the Placebo effect?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, behavioral-economics, placebo

The Placebo effect states that if you and I are both surgeons and we have 10 alike patients each who are in need of knee surgery's, that if you go and do your operations by the book, and I on the other hand do sham ops (Just simply cut the patient open and sew them back up) on my patients, that regardless, over 20% of both our patients will recover with total success from the surgery they had received. And when it comes to psychology this percentage jumps even higher!

Quite simply put, the Placebo effect is our looking glass eye into divine miraculous happenings. What's more is that it is the individual themselves who is performing these miracles. I.E. If you have cancer and believe that cancer will kill you, it will. But if you have cancer, and believe that you will beat that cancer by 100%, you will! They both are correct. But How? Why?

Hence, why, oh why, have we not all looked into this very magical thing that is going on? Are we scared? Do we fear that if we find a way to master this thing called the placebo effect that none of us will have a job? That the need for doctors and medicine will perish? Would that not be a better world?

I would like to know why we have not mastered our understanding and use of the Placebo effect.

Any Takers?

Comment: Are you claiming that if you believe that you will beat cancer - you will?  Do you have evidence for this claim?

Comment: @TonyMobbs - I don't think the OP is suggesting that you can necessarily beat cancer through the placebo effect. Although it was put forward as an **i.e.**, I think in actual fact it is an example in mind given as a possible effect from a possible placebo (mind over matter)?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I am concerned that this question is soliciting opinions rather than evidence-based answers.  I do think there is an interesting question here somewhere, but it needs to be edited to make that clear.  Maybe something like: "What indications does the placebo effect work for?" or "Through what mechanism does the placebo effect work?" or "How is the placebo effect used in clinical practice?"  I would also refrain from making (or implying) unsubstantiated claims.  The question can be reopened once edited.